# Внутренние и вложенные классы JAVA

Tags: java, ооп, классы, inner

Для обращения из внутреннего класса `Inner` к экземпляру обрамляющего класса `Outer` используется следующая запись:

```
Outer.this
```

Можно ли обратиться из класса `Inner` к экземпляру класса, обрамляющего класс `Outer` и при этом не использовать конструкцию `ИмяКлассаОбрамляющегоОбрамляющийКласс.this`?

Есть ли реальное применение такой архитектуре, когда класс содержит внутренние классы, которые в свою очередь тоже содержат внутренние классы?

Comment: Применение такой конструкции с множественным вложением внутренних классов не практично. Все ваши задачи вы можете решить проще. Тут я написал немного о внутренних, вложенных, локальных классах: https://habr.com/ru/post/439648/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

для этого надо использовать наследование от обрамляющего класса, незнаю насколько это практично, но выглядит уродливо

```
class ИмяКлассаВложенногоВВложенныйКласс extends ИмяКлассаОбрамляющегоОбрамляющийКласс {ИмяКлассаОбрамляющегоОбрамляющийКласс sc = this;}
```